# Hiding XML elements with nil="true" with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xml-nil

In my Response.xsd i have many elements like:

```
...
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="carModel" minOccurs="0">
</xs:element>
...
```

I have generated `JAXBClasses` from `.xsd`. Result:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        //...
        "carModel"
        //...
    })
    public static class Car{

    //...
    protected String carModel;
    //...getter and setters.

    }
```

Building my WebService response:

```
  Car car = new Car();
  //other params
  car.setCarModel(null);
```

In generated response im getting:

```
 <ax23:carModel xsi:nil="true"/>
```

But i have expected completly no `carModel` tag at all. I want to skip it completly

What im doing wrong? Why `null` becomes `nil` when `nillable = false` by default.

Im not sure, is that what you were asking for @Xstian:

Part of my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My `WEB-INF/services/CarService/META-INF/services.xml`:

```
<service name="CarService" >
<Description>
    Please Type your service description here
</Description>
<messageReceivers>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
    <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>
<parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.foo.ws.CarService</parameter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this annotation `@XmlElement(nillable=false)`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    //...
    "carModel"
    //...
})
public static class Car{

//...
@XmlElement(nillable=false)
protected String carModel;
//...getter and setters.

}
```

Comment: i have tried it already. It can works however my i see pretty strange thing in my generated WSDL. Even if i will add`@XmlElement(nillable=false)` to `carElement`, wsdl looks like:
`<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="carModel" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>`. What can be reason of that strange generation

Comment: Do you have some `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on `package-info.java`?

Comment: How do you exposed your WS? ..maybe there are some global configurations. Add some details about it.

Comment: i have added some more info.

Comment: Have you tried to use `<service name="CarService" provider="java:RPC" style="document">` to enforce your encoding?

Comment: I tried just now, unfortunetly nothing changed, what is more i have just realised that `@XmlElement(required = true)` is also ignored. Becouse `minOccurs = 0` always